# Why does my AJAX code fail when I try to use the return value?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying use AJAX to make changes to my web page. `xml_whoid.php` seems to work fine. The jQuery works until I add the function (even if it is just the alert). I suspect it is a syntax error but I cannot find the problem.

I also do not know how to access the returned value. I have a jQuery book, but it does not show how to use AJAX return values in a compare statement. I have googled many times but the examples have 
          function(result) {
             "process data here" or "result.data.length"
          }

It seems such a simple problem but I have been tearing my hair out on it because I did not want to ask another (silly) question but can tell by my backup dates I have been stuck on trying to get this AJAX code to work for 5 days.

```
                        xml_whoid.php      
    <?php                                            
    require_once("../../includes/initialize.php");
    require_once("../../includes/functions.php");
    require_once("../../includes/session.php");
    require_once("../../includes/database.php");
    if ($session->is_logged_in()) {
        $idwho=$_POST["idwho"];
        $session->changeidwho($idwho);
        $whos  = Whostaff::find_one_by_who($idwho);
        if ($whos) {
            echo "1";
        } else {
            echo "0";
        }
    }
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function changewho(idwho,mydesc) {
        $('#who').html(mydesc);
        $('#whofoot').html(mydesc);
        $('#whomaint').html(mydesc);
        $("#visible1").show();  
        $("#visible2").show();  
        $("#visible3").show();  
        $("#visible4").show();  
        $("#visible5").show();  
        $.post('xml_whoid.php', { idwho: idwho }); 
        $.ajax({
            url: "xml_whoid.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                idwho: idwho
            },
        function(result) {                 // This code causes everything to fail.
            alert('Fetched');              //
            //if(result==0){               // I have searched and searched but 
            //  $("#visible6").show();     // I cannot work out if this is how 
            //}                            // to access the returned value.
        }                              
    }); 
}  
</script>
```

I use "async: false," because this page is not often used and only in house.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the key `success`:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "xml_whoid.php",
   type: "POST",
   async: false,
   data: {
     idwho: idwho
   },
   success: function(result) {
     alert('Fetched');
   }                              
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The ajax call have a callback function called `success` and another `error`.
With the function success you can retrieve the message that you return from your function.
With the function error you can handle errors from your php page or something wrong.
In your code you have missed to insert the name of the callback function.
try this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "xml_whoid.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                idwho: idwho
            },
            success: function(result) {                
              alert('Fetched');              
            },
            error: function(error) {                 
              alert(error);                                     
            }                              
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Return function should be written as

```
success: function(result) {
  alert('Fetched');
}
```